# Problems with nouislider and LibLink

Tags: nouislider

I am using nouislider anad it works fine except when I try to link it to a span.
Then I get an error: **this.LinkConfirm is not a function**. I am doing it like this:

```
$(function(){
        $('#slider').noUiSlider({
        start: [ 0, 100 ],

        connect: true,
        step:20,
        range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 100
        },
        format: wNumb({
        decimals: 0,

        })
        });

$("#slider").Link('lower').to($('#lower-value'));
$('#slider').on('set', onSlide);
```

Then I have a function:

```
function onSlide(){
    len=$("#slider").val();
    len1=len[0];
    len2=len[1]; 
    };
```

In the html I have:

```
<div id="slider" style="width: 300px"></div>
<br>
<span id="lower-value">Value:</span>    
    <br>
```

Thanks in advance
Hildigunnur

Answer (score 1):

You are building your slider on document ready, (`$(function()`), but you are attempting to `Link` before that happens.

Move the linking up into the `$(function(){ ... });` and it'll work.